# Remove part of the string from beginning of the line up to certain character

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with 10000 lines like this:

```
Peptidyl-prolyl cis-trans isomerase A OS=Homo sapiens GN=PPIA PE=1 SV=2 - [PPIA] 0.8622399654 3.2730004556
```

I cant figure out how to remove part of the string up to square bracket, so that final output looks like this:

```
[PPIA] 0.8622399654 3.2730004556
```

So far I tried python re.sub, but can't match it to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With sed it's a simple substitution:

```
sed 's/^[^[]*\[/[/' input
```

`^` means start of pattern space ("line"), and `[^[]` matches everything but `[`. `*` is a quantifier which means zero or more times. `\[` is a literal `[`.

Comment: I'm not sure "simple" is appropriate *wink*, but points for explaining the pattern and for being first of the sed-solutions.

Comment: I was just commenting on a 29+K user telling a 43 pt user that something is simple after making more than a couple of edits... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

With sed:

```
sed 's/^[^[]*//' file
```

Disadvantage: If a line doesn't contain `[`, sed outputs an empty line.

Comment: ++ for a slight optimization of the accepted answer (not sure why your answer was down-voted).

Comment: what happens with lines that don't contain `[`?

Comment: @thebjorn: They would result in empty output lines, which is a fair point in general, but note the premise of the question: "10000 lines like this".

Comment: Not a problem, but maybe worth a comment in an otherwise code-only answer..?

Comment: @thebjorn: Thank you. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't you actually want to have the last two fields?

```
awk '{print $(NF-1), $NF}' file
```

Otherwise,

```
awk -F'] ' '{print $2}' file
```

(Notice that this also removes the space after the `]`)

Comment: Yes, last two fields are important. Actually, awk '{print $(NF-1), $NF}' did not result in any output.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `sed` solution, assuming that there's at most one `[` on each line:

```
 sed 's/.*\[/[/' file
```

- Making the single-`[` assumption allows for a less "noisy" regular expression that is easier to understand:

  - `s` is Sed's string substitution function, whose arguments are separated with the customary (but selectable) `/` delimiter here.
  - The 1st argument, regular expression `.*\[`, matches the start of any line through the *last* `[` on that line (literal `[` must be represented as `\[`, because `[` has special meaning in a regex).
  - The 2nd argument, `[`, is the replacement string (`[` does *not* need escaping in a replacement-string argument, because it is not a regex itself).
- Since `sed` regular expressions are invariably greedy, `.*\[` matches everything up to the *last* `[` on each line.
- By contrast, the regular expression in [andlrc's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41080173/45375) is more complex, but it predictably only matches up to the *first* `[` (if any).

---

`perl` offers the best of both worlds in this case: a robust up-to-the-first-`[`-only solution that is still reasonably readable:

```
perl -pe 's/.*?\[/[/' file
```

Note the `*?` quantifier, which makes the matching *non-greedy*.

Comment: All Sed solutions above provide desired output, many +++ for detailed explanations of the codes

Comment: @Bio21: Appreciated; unfortunately, the only way to reach all people you want to thank is to comment on their answers individually.

Answer (score 2):

*Python* solution(by using `bytearray.find(sub[, start[, end]])` function):

```
line = 'Peptidyl-prolyl cis-trans isomerase A OS=Homo sapiens GN=PPIA PE=1 SV=2 - [PPIA] 0.8622399654 3.2730004556'
replaced = line[max(line.find('['), 0):]

print(replaced)
```

The output:

```
[PPIA] 0.8622399654 3.2730004556
```

**p.s.** If `[` doesn't occur within a string - the result will be a whole initial string

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
line = line[line.index('['):]
```

if all the lines contain `[`.

A bit more robust:

```
for line in open('myfilename..'):
    if '[' in line:
        print line[line.index('['):]
    else:
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

Piping into sed:

```
sed 's/[^[]*[[]/[/'
```

clips all and only the lines containig at least a `[`